# Decode table construction for base64

Tags: c, base64

I am reading this [libb64](http://libb64.sourceforge.net/) source code for encoding and decoding base64 data.

I know the encoding procedure but i can't figure out how the following decoding table is constructed for fast lookup to perform decoding of encoded base64 characters. This is the table they are using:

```
static const char decoding[] = {62,-1,-1,-1,63,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,-1,-1,-1,-2,-1,-1,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51};
```

Can some one explain me how the values in this table are used for decoding purpose.

Comment: Micro-point: somewhat of a stylistic fail to use signed integers without specifying `signed char`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a shifted and limited ASCII translating table. The keys of the table are ASCII values, the values are base64 decoded values. The table is shifted such that the index `0` actually maps to the ASCII character `+` and any further indices map the ASCII values after `+`. The first entry in the table, the ASCII character `+`, is mapped to the base64 value `62`. Then three characters are ignored (ASCII `,-.`) and the next character is mapped to the base64 value `63`. That next character is ASCII `/`.

The rest will become obvious if you look at that table and the [ASCII table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters).

It's usage is something like this:

```
int decode_base64(char ch) {
    if (ch < `+` or ch > `z`) {
        return SOME_INVALID_CH_ERROR;
    }

    /* shift range into decoding table range */
    ch -= `+`;

    int base64_val = decoding[ch];

    if (base64_val < 0) {
        return SOME_INVALID_CH_ERROR;
    }

    return base64_val;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

As know, each byte has 8 bits, possible 256 combinations with 2 symbols (base2).
With 2 symbols is need to waste 8 chars to represent a byte, for example '01010011'.
With base 64 is possible to represent 64 combinations with 1 char...
So, we have a base table:
   A = 000000
   B = 000001
   C = 000010
   ...
If you have the word 'Man', so you have the bytes:
 01001101, 01100001, 01101110 
and so the stream: 
 011010110000101101110

Break in group of six bits: 010011 010110 000101 101110 
   010011 = T 
   010110 = W 
   000101 = F 
   101110 = u 
So, 'Man' => base64 coded = 'TWFu'. 
As saw, this works perfectly to streams whith length multiple of 6.

If you have a stream that isn't multiple of 6, for example 'Ma' you have the stream:
 010011 010110 0001 
you need to complete to have groups of 6:
 010011 010110 000100 
so you have the coded base 64: 
   010011 = T
   010110 = W
   000100 = E
So, 'Ma' => 'TWE'

After to decode the stream, in this case you need to calc the last multiple length to be multiple of 8 and so remove the extra bits to obtain the original stream:
   T = 010011
   W = 010110
   E = 000100
1) 010011 010110 000100
2) 01001101 01100001 00
3) 01001101 01100001 = 'Ma'
In really, when we put the trailing 00s, we mark the end of Base64 string with '=' to each trailing '00 added ('Ma' ==> Base64 'TWE=')

See too the link: http://www.base64decode.org/

Images represented on base 64 is a good option to represent with strings in many applications where is hard to work directly with a real binary stream. Real binary stream is better because is a base256, but is difficult inside HTML for example, there are 2 ways, minor traffic, or more easy to work with strings.

See ASCII codes too, the chars of base 64 is from range '+' to 'z' on table ASCII but there are some values between '+' and 'z' that isn't base 64 symbols

   '+' = ASCII DEC 43
   ...
   'z' = ASCII DEC 122
   from DEC 43 to 122 are 80 values but
   43 OK = '+'
   44 isn't a base 64 symbols so the decoding index is -1 (invalid symbol to base64)
   45 ....
   46  ...
   ...
   122 OK = 'z'
do the char needed to decode, decremented of 43 ('+') to be index 0 on vector to quick access by index so, decoding[80] = {62, -1, -1 ........, 49, 50,51};


   Roberto Novakosky
   Developer Systems

Answer (score 0):

Considering these 2 mapping tables:

```
static const char decodingTab[] = {62,-1,-1,-1,63,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,-1,-1,-1,-2,-1,-1,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51};
static unsigned char encodingTab[64]="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";
```

decodingTab is the reverse mapping table of encondingTab. 
So decodingTab[i] should never be -1.
In fact, only 64 values are expected. However decodingTab size is 128.
So, in decodingTab,unexpected index values are set to -1 (an arbitrary number which is not in [0,63])

```
char c;
unsigned char i;
...
encoding[decoding[c]]=c;
decoding[encoding[i]=i;
```

Hope it helps.